# Books for studying matrices at a high school level

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm teaching matrices at a high school level and I'm looking for good books in this subject.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like it would be pretty easy to make your own notes on the subject at the high school level.

Comment: @GregoryGrant The most important is the problems. Maybe there are some books with interesting ones, besides it takes time to write notes on this subject on latex.

Comment: This book by Lang might be appropriate, take a look at the preview.  It's for undergrads but you can probably read much of it in HS if you have reasonably decent students (which I assume you do because LA is usually not a HS topic).  http://smile.amazon.com/Introduction-Linear-Algebra-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387962050

Comment: Also this book as a chapter on LA that's pretty basic: http://smile.amazon.com/Basic-Mathematics-Serge-Lang/dp/0387967877

Comment: I suggest doing a google search on "introduction linear algebra pdf" and you'll find a ton of free treatments of the subject you can probably find one that works for your students.

Comment: Related is [Reference books for learning matrices from the beginning?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1520465/reference-books-for-learning-matrices-from-the-beginning), and in my answer I cite the School Mathematics Study Group (a well-known U.S.A. "new math" high school series of books from the 1960s) volume [**Introduction to Matrix Algebra**](http://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED135631.pdf), which is now freely available on the internet. The table of contents gives a good indication of what is covered.

Comment: If you're teaching both vectors and matrices and would be happy to focus on applications in dimensions 2 and 3 (vector geometry, reduction of conics, etc.), perhaps have a look at *Pure Mathematics* by Parsonson. It deals especially with questions that would be of interest at the high school level (geared towards year 13 school-leaving exams in the UK in the 1970s). While it is rigorous and has interesting problems, including theoretical ones, its approach is much more concrete than is typical in university-level books. Of 29 chapters, 9 are on vectors and linear algebra.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to study "Linear Algebra Done Right" of Axler. It is a text at undergraduate level but is very accessible.

Comment: Si dice "try" non si dice "prove" in questo caso.